# New user in AD should be added to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, active-directory

We have a requirement where when the System Admin add a new user in Active Directory, an entry of this user should be added to our SQL Server `User` table.

The basic operation would be like when added, modify and deleted. Of course when deleted we need to turn the BIT to false so the user will not be able to access any features when they try to login to our application.

[Edit]

1. How to go about doing this?
2. Any pointers/sample code/references

[More details]

We need the user details to be in our SQL Server table as the configuration for our application to run is set in SQL Server. Hence when the user is added in AD automatically we have to add the same user to our DB table later our application admin (different from AD admin) will give permission and roles to access the application.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @MikeW Added my questions now...

Comment: firstly you'll need to work out the C# code to retrieve the AD objects.  Then you can either setup a scheduled running of your C# prog to get the latest users and alter your Users table, or you have some always running service that checks.

Comment: @cjb110 cant we use the AD push technology instead to call the required web service?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to create a group in AD and put this group to SQL Server, then add users to this group in AD?

Comment: This cannot be possible. I have edited my question to explain this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Tell me one good reason why you are maintaining parallel user directory with AD. Instead of creating your new user-defined wrapper over AD for "Authentication" just concentrate on "Authorization" as joey said. Use User-Groups and Roles for mapping your application's access and accessibility levels.
Of course for controlling the access of application you can use Sql Server.